# Therubyracer on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make "twitter-bootstrap-rails" work with Rails 3.2.
It depends on "therubyracer"

When I add "therubyracer" and do bundle command it gives errors.

```
...
Failed to build gem native extension
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking ro w8.h... no
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.
Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from 'therubyracer' gem , you have to install 'execjs' gem also.

Write `gem 'therubyracer'`, and `gem 'execjs'` in your gem file. And run `bundle install`.

The above will go fine.